# How do I display price of selected bundle products instead of "From $"?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a product consisting of a bundle of 5 products. All of these products are optional but checked on default. Therefore the main product is displayed as "From 900 kr." instead of displaying the price of the selected items. I am using WooCommerces own plugin called "WooCommerce Product Bundles".

[picture of the product page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ev7yu.png)

The total price is already shown underneath the bundle options but I want that to be showed as the main price area.

I've already succeeded with this on variable product types and thought i could use the same code with a few changes. Sadly I couldn't make it work.

The code I used for the variable products:

```
// Show selected variation price in main price area

add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'selected_variation_price_replace_variable_price_range');
function selected_variation_price_replace_variable_price_range(){
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type('variable') ):
    ?><style> .woocommerce-variation-price {display:none;} </style>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        var p = 'p.price'
            q = $(p).html();

        $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function( event, data ) {
            if ( data.price_html ) {
                $(p).html(data.price_html);
            }
        }).on('hide_variation', function( event ) {
            $(p).html(q);
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

EDIT:

I've hidden the main price on the product page and styled the bundle price to look like the main price. The problem now lies on the category page where the price doesn't display the price of the default selected variation of the bundles. It shows the max possible price for the product and not the default bundle selection price.

Here's the code from the bundle plugin that results in a max price display:

```
/**
                 * 'woocommerce_bundle_force_old_style_price_html' filter.
                 *
                 * Used to suppress the range-style display of bundle price html strings.
                 *
                 * @param  boolean            $force_suppress_range_format
                 * @param  WC_Product_Bundle  $this
                 */
                if ( $suppress_range_price_html || apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bundle_force_old_style_price_html', false, $this ) ) {

                    $price = wc_price( $price_max );

                    $regular_price_min = $this->get_bundle_regular_price( 'max', true );

                    if ( $regular_price_min !== $price_max ) {

                        $regular_price = wc_price( $regular_price_max );

                        if ( $price_min !== $price_max ) {
                            $price = sprintf( _x( '%1$s%2$s', 'Price range: from', 'woocommerce-product-bundles' ), wc_get_price_html_from_text(), wc_format_sale_price( $regular_price, $price ) . $this->get_price_suffix() );
                        } else {
                            $price = wc_format_sale_price( $regular_price, $price ) . $this->get_price_suffix();
                        }
```

Since the price displays and effectively changes upon variation change within the product page that code must also be available to use for the shop loop I just can't seem to find it.

Comment: I have just tested this code and works fine for me. can you share the site URL?

Comment: @Bhautik The code works on a variable product type but not on bundle product type. Here's er URL: 

https://staging.coolenergi.dk/produkt/komplet-luft-til-vand-varmepumpe-pakke-12kw/

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are only checking for product type `variable`. You have to check for `bundle` as well.

Simply you have to add more conidition with `or` `$product->is_type('bundle')`

Check the below code.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'selected_variation_price_replace_variable_price_range');
function selected_variation_price_replace_variable_price_range(){
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type('variable') || $product->is_type('bundle') ):
    ?><style> .woocommerce-variation-price {display:none;} </style>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        var p = 'p.price'
            q = $(p).html();

        $('form.cart').on('show_variation', function( event, data ) {
            if ( data.price_html ) {
                $(p).html(data.price_html);
            }
        }).on('hide_variation', function( event ) {
            $(p).html(q);
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
```

**UPDATE:** try the below code. code will go in your active theme function.php file.

```
function override_woocommerce_bundle_default_variation_price_html( $price, $product ) {

    if( $product->is_type('variable') || $product->is_type('bundle') ){
        
        $bundled_items = $product->get_bundled_items();

        if ( ! empty( $bundled_items ) ) {

            foreach ( $bundled_items as $bundled_item ) {

                foreach( $bundled_item->product->get_available_variations() as $pav ){
                    $def = true;
                    foreach( $bundled_item->product->get_variation_default_attributes() as $defkey => $defval ){
                        if( $pav['attributes']['attribute_'.$defkey] != $defval){
                            $def = false;             
                        }   
                    }
                    if( $def ){
                        $price = $pav['display_price'];         
                    }
                }   
                
            }
            
        }

        return wc_price($price);
    }

    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'override_woocommerce_bundle_default_variation_price_html', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: thank you for looking into it. Sadly I've already tried that and it doesn't work. The price changes but it's inaccurate as if it only counts one of the variables.

The price is just 3.000, 3.200, or 3.500 even though there are products included for almost 50.000.

Comment: I have checked on your site and looks like it's working.

Comment: How have you checked if the code works? It does not work for me...
I've done other adjustments to the site by hiding the main price perhaps that's what you are referring to and think it works?

Comment: Ah, Yes maybe...

Comment: The current fix on the product page is fine but on the shop loop I made it shows the "max" bundle price but the price is now showing the highest possible price and not the price of the default selected variable prices. As you can see the product on the shop loop says 51.498 but on the product page, it says the correct price: 50.498...

Comment: Yes, I can see. can you put the code on a question which you add for display price on the shop page?.

Comment: I've added an edit note to this post with the code in question.

Comment: Can you show how you set up that bundled product and default variation?

Comment: As you can see on this screenshot: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/29812620?key=8f2f9d04eaf330e1477e45c35b6302a9

I've ticked the option "Override Default Selections".

Comment: Check my updated answer and let me know if that's works

Comment: Can't save the code as there's an error with this line that breaks the site:

Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WC_Product_Simple::get_available_variations() in wp-content/themes/blocksy-child/functions.php:386

Comment: I have updated again.

Comment: same error again: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/29816829?key=1b7d69605c9870a0c11026a18dc2892d

Comment: I have just set it up on my local and working fine for me. now it's required to debug on your site.

Comment: I've tried on various sites, and the same error code occurs even with fresh woocommerce installation and clean functions.php. Are there any differences in the code you are using on your site?

Comment: Not sure but now it's required to debug on your site.